# Cannot connect PHP to SQLServer 2012

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using xampp and I'm trying to connect my PHP project to SQL Server to make reports. But there's a conflict with **sqlsrv_connect()** function.

My version of PHP installed in XAMPP is 5.6.23 and my connection file contains this:

```
<?php
$serverName = "MyserverName\MyinstanceName"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Database_Example");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Also, I have downloaded the next files and I have extracted in "C:\xampp\php". [PHP dll's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkKkw.png)

And I have added to "php.ini" file this code:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
```

I´ve tried too with the exact version of the driver for my PHP and it doesn´t work.

[Drivers Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqMGK.png)

And this is the **error** that appears when I'm trying to connect:

***Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\conexion.proc.php***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my own problem! I write the answer for someone with the same problem.

The version of the driver have to be the same of your PHP, not superior. You have to **extract** the dll files in "C:\xampp\php\ext" not in "C:\xampp\php".

After that another problem will appear:
[ODBC Driver 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2FzN.png)

You have to dowload **ODBC Driver** 11 on this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36434

And then when the driver will be installed, your code with queries will work!